Using transistors with constant current driver
I am trying to drive a couple LEDs using a constant current driver and transistors to switch between them. I modeled two of them in LTspice, and they behaved as expected, but when I soldered the circuit I got unexpected results.

When I made my real life circuit, I connect all the positive leads of my LEDs to the positive output from my LED driver and all the negative outputs to the collector of their respective TIP31C transistors. I then connect the emitters to a shared ground which attaches to the negative lead from my LED driver.
This appears to work to separate the LEDs, but each of my LEDs are very dim when turned on. When I short the collector to LED ground, the LED turns on at the expected brightness. I have been trying to troubleshoot this as someone who is new to electronics and am confused, so any help is appreciated.

The Meanwell driver you are using has some internal circuitry; the "-" output lead is not connected directly to ground (probably there is a low-side sense resistor but it's not documented what is going on internally).
If we assume a low-side sense resistor then your base current is subtracting from the LED current.
You might be able to get this to work essentially as-is by swapping out the ancient TIP31 BJTs for logic level MOSFETs.
